# PHP to sort an array contains memory strings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Rather than defining the order values in the array. Can I sort this array by ascending order using PHP?

```
<?php
$memories = array('32GB', '64GB', '128GB', '16GB');
?>
```

Thank you!

**Updated**: using PHP 5.3

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Will all the values in the array always be in GB? That's obviously quite important with regards to the solution.

Comment: @chris yes, it is.

Comment: Then I think @Marcus has you covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP <= v5.3**

Check out [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$memories = array('32GB', '64GB', '128GB', '16GB');
natsort($memories);

print_r($memories); // Array ( [3] => 16GB [0] => 32GB [1] => 64GB [2] => 128GB )
```

**PHP >= v5.4**

Sure can with [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and a `SORT_NATURAL` flag.

```
<?php
$memories = array('32GB', '64GB', '128GB', '16GB');
sort($memories, SORT_NATURAL);

print_r($memories); // [0] => '16GB', [1] => '32GB', [2] => '64GB', [3] => '128GB'
```

Comment: Is there alternative way to make this works on PHP 5.3? Tested with 5.4 (staging) and it worked. But our production server is still using 5.3

Comment: Manual states the `sort()` function covers "PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7". Did you test it on your production server? No reason it shouldn't work on 5.3. On another note, your dev/prod servers should be running the same version of PHP (MySQL, etc, etc, etc; Testing on one version of x and deploying to another version of x can have dire consequences).

Comment: This is what it threw out: `NOTICE Use of undefined constant SORT_NATURAL - assumed 'SORT_NATURAL' on line number 4` on 5.3

Comment: Ah shoot. From the manual: "v5.4: Added support for SORT_NATURAL". You're right. Doesn't appear to work with < 5.4. Missed that.

Comment: I agree on the version issue that both servers should have the same version, but I can't do anything on that. :(

Comment: Updated my answer above to reflect 5.3 and 5.4